# Term for a small businessman who is exempt from paying VAT

Tags: phrase-request

In Israel there is a special term "Osek Patur" for a business-owner who is exempt from paying taxes because his annual income is small. What is a parallel term in English? "Exempt businessman"? "Exempt businessowner"? Some other term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK, "VAT exempt" is the term for a business that is so small that it doesn't have to register for VAT, currently that is the case if the business has an annual revenue of less than £82,000. For example, a window cleaning business consisting of one man, one ladder, and one bucket, may be VAT exempt. In practice more important is whether the business is VAT registered or not. A VAT exempt business can choose to register for VAT or not (which has its advantages and disadvantages) , a non-exempt business has no choice but must register. I have never seen a word for "not VAT registered".

Being exempt from paying *taxes* is something entirely different. The threshold for not having to file your taxes is so low, you wouldn't call it a business. Don't hold me to the number, but it's less than £2,000 revenue (not profit) a year.

Answer (score 1):

The term you refer to is specific to Israel based on the local tax laws. A rough equivalent is [tax exempt organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_exemption#Exempt_organizations), or perhaps more specifically *tax exempt business* or *person*, but these refer to exemption in general; it may be due to reasons othen than small income.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on local tax-code.  In the US there is no such thing as "exempt business-owner". VAT and income-tax are two different things.  Businesses do not pay sales tax, and therefore all businesses are tax-exempt, when it comes to VAT or sales-tax.  In the US sales-tax is only collected once, on the end user.